# Laravel mix not working with thread-loader + ts-loader

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I am trying to increase my build speeds using Laravel Mix. I am trying to use the `thread-loader` with the `ts-loader` to do so as one of the optimisations. The relevant part of the webpack config for it looks like:

```
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'thread-loader',
                        options: {
                            workers: os.cpus().length - 1,
                            poolTimeout: Mix.isWatching() ? Infinity : 500,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: {
                            happyPackMode: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
```

But when I compile it gets an error complaining about a react file of mine which works fine without the thread loader:

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/js/src/building/issues/Grid.tsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: .../resources/assets/js/src/building/issues/Grid.tsx: Unexpected token (35:89)
  33 |     Grid.prototype.renderGrid = function (id, chartManager) {
  34 |         this.container = document.getElementById(id);
> 35 |         this.component = ReactDOM.render(chartManager, { chartManager: chartManager } /  > , this.container);
     |                                                                                          ^
  36 |     };
```

But if I add `mix.dump()` to dump the webpack config on build, it works just fine. I am thinking maybe it is a race condition or something. Any ideas?